# Using QSimpleXmlNodeModel and QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

I've been looking at ways to populate a QTreeView with data from an XML file.  The XML will be simple.  I've come across QSimpleXmlNodeModel and have been trying to figure out if this is suitable for my needs, but can't find any examples of its use.

Can someone point me to an example or post some code to get me started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example delivered with Qt.
Take a look at [xmlpatterns/filetree](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxmlpatterns-xmlpatterns-filetree-example.html) example.

It is not that easy as with some other models. You have to implement these abstract methods:

```
QUrl QAbstractXmlNodeModel::documentUri(const QXmlNodeModelIndex &) const
QXmlNodeModelIndex::NodeKind QAbstractXmlNodeModel::kind(const QXmlNodeModelIndex &) const
QXmlNodeModelIndex::DocumentOrder QAbstractXmlNodeModel::compareOrder(const QXmlNodeModelIndex &,const QXmlNodeModelIndex &) const
QXmlNodeModelIndex QAbstractXmlNodeModel::root(const QXmlNodeModelIndex &) const
QXmlName QAbstractXmlNodeModel::name(const QXmlNodeModelIndex &) const
QVariant QAbstractXmlNodeModel::typedValue(const QXmlNodeModelIndex &) const
QXmlNodeModelIndex QAbstractXmlNodeModel::nextFromSimpleAxis(QAbstractXmlNodeModel::SimpleAxis,const QXmlNodeModelIndex &) const
QVector<T> QAbstractXmlNodeModel::attributes(const QXmlNodeModelIndex &) const
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  It gets me started for sure, but is more work than I hoped it would be.  Time to roll my sleeves up and get stuck in.